# Setting at attribute in JSF portlet through selenium

Tags: jsf-2, selenium, primefaces, liferay-6

I am writing a Integration test. I need to send a mandatory field as blank just to check whats the server response , but the request is not sent as it has attribute **"required=true"** . So I want to set the attribute **"immediate=true"** in my submit button through selenium test case. Any idea how to do that.

below is the code snippet of submit button:

```
          <h:panelGroup id="panel_commands" layout="block" styleClass="atf-inline-block atf-w70p">
                    <p:commandButton value="#{I18N['key_button_submit_ticket']}"
                        title="#{I18N['key_button_submit_ticket']}" actionListener="#{createTicketBaseBean.createTicketData}"
                        action="#{createTicketBaseBean.createTicket}"
                        styleClass="atf-right" process="@form" update="@form" id="submit_button">
                    </p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the immediate attribute has to be set on the server. You can use EL like  and then have a MyBean.isImmedate() method that returns true/false based on whatever you want. In your MyBean class, perhaps you could examine the HTTP header to see if it is an integration test, or you could examine a Java system property that you set via JAVA_OPTS when you start your server in integration-test mode.